# Trying to get index of object in localstorage so I can delete/remove that object from localStorage storage, using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

all, This is my first question here, so I hope I'm phrasing it correctly and providing enough information with which to work.

I have a key in local storage called faveGifs, which has several items stored in it, each of which is an object. I want to be able to delete these objects individually. So far, I can delete the first object, the one at position 0. I want to be able to delete them at whichever index they are at, like position 2 for example. I know I have to get the indexes of each of the objects so I can achieve this, however, when I run the key through indexOf(), the only indexes I get is -1.

Here is how my localstorage key looks:

```
faveGifs[
  {id: 'jijijoj',rating: 'g'}, 
  {id: 'iojiojoi',rating: 'r'}, 
  {id: 'eawfe',rating: 'pg'}, 
  {id: 'ewfewfwe',rating: 'g'}, 
  {id: 'ewfewfew',rating: 'r'}
];
```

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#remove", function () {
  let faveGifs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("faveGifs"));
  let faveGif = faveGifs.map(faveGif => faveGif.id);

  //Neither of the following has worked for me:

  //let index = faveGif.indexOf(faveGif);
  //let index = faveGif.indexOf(faveGifs);
  console.log(index);

  // faveGifs.splice(index, 1);
  // localStorage.setItem("faveGifs", JSON.stringify(faveGifs));
  // populateFaves();
});
```

I have tried using solutions from similar questions, but none of them have worked for me. The ones I have tried are:

[Remove a specific item from localstorage with js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50478508/remove-a-specific-item-from-localstorage-with-js)

[Remove json object in localstorage using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29215088/remove-json-object-in-localstorage-using-js)

[How do I remove an object from an array with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396088/how-do-i-remove-an-object-from-an-array-with-javascript)

And several others, but like I said, none of them have worked for me.

Many thanks to anyone and everyone who helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `faveGif` is still an array - it would look like this:

```
faveGif = ['jijijoj', 'iojiojoi', 'eawfe', 'ewfewfwe', 'ewfewfew'];
```

So if you want to find the index of a certain ID (let's say `ewfewfew`):

```
let index = faveGif.findIndex(id => id == "ewfewfew");
```

This would be the same index as in `faveGifs`, so it would give you the required result.

Demonstration:

```js
let faveGifs = [{
  id: 'jijijoj',
  rating: 'g'
}, {
  id: 'iojiojoi',
  rating: 'r'
}, {
  id: 'eawfe',
  rating: 'pg'
}, {
  id: 'ewfewfwe',
  rating: 'g'
}, {
  id: 'ewfewfew',
  rating: 'r'
}];

let faveGif = faveGifs.map(faveGif => faveGif.id);

let index = faveGif.findIndex(id => id == "ewfewfew");

console.log(index); //Should return 4
```

Answer (score 0):

To get index of element in array you can use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Code:

```js
const data = [
  {id: 'jijijoj',rating: 'g'}, 
  {id: 'iojiojoi',rating: 'r'}, 
  {id: 'eawfe',rating: 'pg'}, 
  {id: 'ewfewfwe',rating: 'g'}, 
  {id: 'ewfewfew',rating: 'r'}
];

// get index of element with id `iojiojoi`
const index = data.findIndex(item => item.id === 'iojiojoi');

console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is going on is that you are attempting to parse a string, as if it were JSON.

Check out this post: [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage). The OP was attempting to solve a similar problem.